# installing a non-gui emacs on Catalina without using a package manager

Tags: terminal, emacs

I would like to install a non-gui version of emacs on a Catalina machine --- an emacs which is like the emacs which was part of the pre-Catalina macs.

My usage of emacs will be when i ssh into the Catalina machine from another host.  I will never need mouse support because i'll be on a remote host.

The mg program is nice, but i need to be able to run multiple shells and other programs inside emacs, so mg won't do.

I have not yet settled on a package manager for the Catalina machine, so i don't want the emacs to be tied to any particular package manager (such as home brew or mac ports or fink).

So: i'm not looking for an Emacs.app type of thing, just a plain, simple emacs (but that can run shells and elisp and dired and the other emacs things).

Comment: Well, as it happens, installation of a non-gui emacs is easy to do if you are willing to use the gui.  You visit https://emacsformacosx.com , then download the dmg file, then double click it (to mount it), then drag the app to /Applications .  Then in your ~/.zshrc (creating it if necessary) you add a line

**alias emacs=/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/emacs-nw**

A better installation solution would both avoid the use of the gui, as well as not require installation of a package manager (such as home brew).